# Standalone UINavigationBar and MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using a standalone UINavigationBar with one button that toggles a side menu on the left. It works flawlessly.

Now I wanted to add a email feedback form using MFMailComposeViewController. It shows up and I can edit all the fields (To, Subject, Body) but when I want to "send" the button doesn't react. When I go to click "Cancel" I notice that the functionality of the underlying UINavigationBar button triggers. It seems as if my UINavigationBar is "above" the NavigationBar of the email compose dialog even though I only see the email compose dialog.

Is there any way to ensure that the MFMailComposeViewController is on top of everything else?

Thanks

Comment: How are you adding the UINavigationBar, and how are you presenting the mail composer?

Comment: Show us the code you'r using to present the mail composer...

Comment: It is kind of difficult to show the code. I have a parent view that has a subview in which a view gets loaded that then in turn initiates the MFMailComposeViewController. The parent view has the UINavigationBar (drag/drop onto the XIB). The code for the MFMailComposeViewController is very simple and as follows     

- (IBAction)btnSendEmailPressed:(id)sender {
    
    MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"MYEMAILADDRESS"]];

Comment: [controller setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MYSUBJECT", [self bundleVersionNumber]]];
        [controller setMessageBody:@"MYBODY" isHTML:NO];
    
    if (controller) 
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    
    [controller release];
    
}

Comment: All that happens on the parent view is that I have an IBAction method that is triggered by the tapping of the button in the UINavigationBar. In that method I do the following: 
    MyViewController *subView = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
    [[subView view] setTag:105];
    [[self contentView] addSubview:[subView view]];
    
And in the subViews view there is a UIButton that triggers the method above.

Answer (score 2):

I see you're setting the delegate to `self`, which is good, but are you also implementing the following method?

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I would guess that cancelling is somehow handled without dismissing the composing view controller?

I would also try modifying the following line:

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

to this:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

If you're using a navigation bar, as you said, then try presenting from your view controller's nab controller instead.

This could be something weird like a strange interaction with `wantsFullscreenLayout` of your view controller. Double check all your nib connections, and if it's still not working, try pushing another, "test" view controller. It could be something with your code or nib and not the `MFMailComposeViewController` itself.